# Check if a user tag is real discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I'm making a discord bot with a website. There is a form on the website, it requires you to put your discord tag (user#0000). So what i want to do is when you submit it, it checks if submitted tag is a real user.

Couldn't find anything.

Thanks.

Edit: Here is the post code

```
const fs = require("fs")
 
module.exports = (req,res,client) => {
  let db = require("./feedback.json") 
 
  let d = true
 
  let user = client.users.cache.find(u => u.tag == req.body.user) // What i tried
  
  if (user == undefined) {
    d = false
  } else {
    db.forEach((e) => {
      if (e.dcName == req.body.dcName) {
        d = false
      }
    })
  }
 
  if (d == true) {
    db.push(req.body)
  }
 
  fs.writeFile("./webserver/feedback.json", JSON.stringify(db), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
  })
  
  if (d == true) {
    res.redirect("/feedback?msg=0")
  } else {
    res.redirect("/feedback?msg=1")
  }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: @Tyler2P Here is the post code: https://pastebin.com/zDKTsTB1

Comment: Please post your code directly to the question, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.

Comment: @Tyler2P I edited the question to have the code in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to check whether your specified user tag is real unless that user is in the bot cache. You might want to request they put a user ID (and then fetch with client.users.fetch, which will always give you the user object if the user ID is real).

I can't rewrite your code without more information, however, please look into `client.users.fetch()` so you can make sure that if your user uses the bot, the bot has the user cached.